# How to update workspace with a defunct element in stream in Accurev

Tags: accurev

I am facing a problem while updating my workspace. One user has defuncted a file and promoted that. Now when I am trying to update my workspace, error occured, it says: "Element would be stranded .----------\abc.txt
Some elements would be stranded as a result of an update.
You will need to resolve this prior to trying update again.
Display the File Browser Incoming Changes mode to see what
might be causing elements to become stranded.
Update failed."

How to resolve it.

Answer (score 2):

Select the file abc.txt -> right click -> Revert To Basis version.
Once you have purged this file, you can update your workspace.

Answer (score 1):

A file or directory becomes (stranded) when the parent directory has been defuncted. So in your case you're working on the file abc.txt and someone else has defuncted the directory, or parent directory where this file resides.

To resolve this you will either have to accurev mv abc.txt ../someplace/where/the/directory/exists or undefunct the directory where abc.txt resides.